# Can flutter do scanning directories (recursive)?

Tags: flutter, dart, recursion, directory

I need to scan my `assets` directory for other files and directories, like

```
-assets
   -category1
      -file.1
   -category2
      -file.1
      -file.2
```

Is it possible **at all** using Flutter, Dart? Can't find any guide to scan directories.

Answer (score 3):

```
import 'dart:io';

void main(List<String> args) async {

FileSystemEntity entity = Directory.current;

  if (args.isNotEmpty) {
    //if you pass the/path/you/wish
    //this block will be handled  
    String arg = args.first;
    entityForAbsolutePath = FileSystemEntity.isDirectorySync(arg) ? Directory(arg) : File(arg);
  }

  var dir = Directory(entityForAbsolutePath.absolute.path);

  Stream<File> scannedFiles = scanningFilesWithAsyncRecursive(dir);

  scannedFiles.listen((File file) {
    print(file.path);
  });
}

//async* + yield* for recursive functions
Stream<File> scanningFilesWithAsyncRecursive(Directory dir) async* {

  //dirList is FileSystemEntity list for every directories/subdirectories
  //entities in this list might be file, directory or link 
  var dirList = dir.list();
  await for (final FileSystemEntity entity in dirList) {
    if (entity is File) {
      yield entity;
    } else if (entity is Directory){
      yield* scanningFilesWithAsyncRecursive(Directory(entity.path));
    }
  }
}
```

You can benefit from this idea.

if you run this snippet as entry point, like this:

```
$ dart your_dart_project/bin/main.dart /home/uname/any/absolute/path/you/wish
```

it will take the/any/path/you/wish as root and travers all of subdirectories and prints every file name as absolute path like:

```
home/uname/any/absolute/path/you/wish/myfile.any
home/uname/any/absolute/path/you/wish/myfile1.any
home/uname/any/absolute/path/you/wish/subdir/mysubdirfile1.any
home/uname/any/absolute/path/you/wish/subdir/mysubdirfile2.any
home/uname/any/absolute/path/you/wish/subdir/inner/myinnerfile1.any
```

P.S. if you will not show any path to dart command like this:

```
$ dart your_dart_project/bin/main.dart
```

it will travers in the directory `your_dart_project/bin`,
the line `FileSystemEntity entity = Directory.current;` tells about it

Comment: Try adding some comments to the code so its a bit more useful for any future readers.

Answer (score 0):

You can read platform files and directories if you can load "dart:io" (everything but flutter web).  This **doesn't** work for the assets.  The `rootBundle` can give you a json string added during the build which lists the assets and fonts (`AssetManifest.json` and `FontManifest.json`), but otherwise, there are really no "directories" in the asset bundle, just assets accessible using a path-like syntax.